# modal dialog in jquery that doesn't block the whole site

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

how to achieve this?
let's say that I have 3 dialogs A, B and C. I can work with them at the same time by having them one next to the other, drag them around, put them one on top of another, etc...
now, at some point, the B dialog opens a dialog X. I must still be able to work with dialogs A and C but I must not be able to work with B until I close X.
like the "modal" approach of visual basic
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest thing would be to use the "disable" method of dialog B when X opens and then call "enable" on B when X closes.

Comment: hey lomaxx! I tried your suggestion. the thing is that when disabling B, this dialog gets "grayed" but I can still drag it around, bring it in front of X and even perform other tasks in B dialog :(

Answer (score 0):

Find the width and height of dialog B and create an overlay on that dialog alone with a message telling the user the action they must take to clear that overlay.

I would also suggest providing a visual prompt any time the user tries to select dialog B while dialog X is open. Something as simple as throbbing the border of dialog a few times would be more than enough.

You may want to explore a way of visually defining the relationship between dialog B and dialog X as well, so that moving one will move the other.